# Change Highfaces Chart default Label

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i want to send a text from a input field to a bootsfaces textarea. But, i wonder, it dosen't work. I use Javascript to get the click event from the button and fire the send-Method in the javascript code:

My HTML looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:b="http://bootsfaces.net/ui">

<h:head>
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js" type="text/javascript" />
<script src="js/websocket.js" type="text/javascript" />
</h:head>
<h:body>


<div class="toogleClass">
    <h:form>
        <b:panel look="primary" title="CHAT" collapsible="false">
            <b:inputTextarea rows="10" id="messages"></b:inputTextarea>
            <b:panelGrid colSpans="8,4">
                <b:inputText placeholder="Nachricht" id="message"></b:inputText>
                <b:button value="senden" look="primary" id="button"
                    onclick="send()"></b:button>
            </b:panelGrid>
        </b:panel>
    </h:form>
</div>

<b:icon name="envelope" size="3x" styleClass="message"
    tooltip="Verfasse eine Nachricht im Chat" />
<br />
```

Ant his i my websocket.js code:

```
var websocket = new WebSocket(
"ws://" +
document.location.host +
document.location.pathname +
"chat");

websocket.onopen = function onOpen() {
var m = document.getElementById("messages");
if (typeof m !== 'undefined' && m !== null) {
    m.append("Verbunden");
}
};

websocket.onmessage = function onMessage(evt) {
var m = document.getElementById("messages");
if (typeof m !== 'undefined' && m !== null) {
    m.append(evt.data);
}
};

websocket.onclose = function onMessage(evt) {
var m = document.getElementById("messages");
if (typeof m !== 'undefined' && m !== null) {
    m.append(evt.data);
}
};

function send() {
var inputtext = document.getElementById("message");
if (typeof inputtext !== 'undefined' && inputtext !== null) {
    websocket.send(inputtext.val());
    document.getElementById("message").val("");
}

}
;
```

my script.js:

```
$(function() {

$('.message').click(function() {
    $('.toogleClass').toggle("slow");
});


});
```

All in all, nothing happens. The message from the input field is not append in the textarea if i clikc the button. No exception, no mistake from the debug console.

Comment: BTW, I don't see any connection between your code and HighFaces. Would you mind to change the title of the question to make it more useful for other developers stumbling into the same problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The real id of the input field is not what you'd expect from HTML programming. JSF makes sure the id is unique on the page, even if the input field is iterated in a data table or a `<ui:repeat>` loop. To reach this goal, the "clientId" is concatenated from the id of the form, the id of the input field itself and sometimes some other parent widgets. BootsFaces makes things even more complicated. It gives the entire widget the regular clientId, so JSF AJAX updates work properly. As a consequence, it often renames the actual input field which is nested in other divs.

In your case, the ids of the input field and the text area are probably something like `input_j_idt5:j_idt12:message` and `input_j_idt5:j_idt12:messages`.

Adding insult to injury, the fragments `j_idt5` and `j_idt12` change when you add or remove input fields at the beginning of the form.

Therefore, I recommend to use CSS pseudo classes instead of ids. The idea being that you add a CSS class to the input field and to the text area. You don't need to provide a CSS rule for these two classes. It suffices that they are there. This allows you to access the input field using `document.getElementsByClassName("message-class")[0]` or the jQuery expression `$(".message-class")`.